# R C5.0 get rule and probability for every leaf

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree, party

I think during my research to solve this question I came pretty close. I am looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29638602/3695715) for the C5.0 package.

The method provided in the SO answer works with a `party` object. However the C5.0 package does not support `as.party`. On my further research I found [this comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192382/r-c5-0-tree-model-to-list-conversion#comment369090_192382) that the maintainer of the C5.0 package already programmed the function, but did not export it.

I thought great this should work, but unfortunately the suggested function `C50:::as.party.C5.0(mod1)` throws the error:

```
error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
    cannot coerce class ""function"" to a data.frame
```

Any suggestions to solve this error appreciated.
Let's use the following example:

```
library(C50)
p = iris[1:4]
t = factor(iris$Species)
model = C50::C5.0(p,t)
#summary(model)

modParty = C50:::as.party.C5.0(model)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to occur when using the default method of `C5.0()` as opposed to the formula method. If you use the latter then the `as.party()` conversion works successfully and you can apply all methods for that:

```
model <- C5.0(Species ~ ., data = iris)
modParty <- C50:::as.party.C5.0(model)
modParty
## Model formula:
## Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width
## 
## Fitted party:
## [1] root
## |   [2] Petal.Length <= 1.9: setosa (n = 50, err = 0.0%)
## |   [3] Petal.Length > 1.9
## |   |   [4] Petal.Width <= 1.7
## |   |   |   [5] Petal.Length <= 4.9: versicolor (n = 48, err = 2.1%)
## |   |   |   [6] Petal.Length > 4.9: virginica (n = 6, err = 33.3%)
## |   |   [7] Petal.Width > 1.7: virginica (n = 46, err = 2.2%)
## 
## Number of inner nodes:    3
## Number of terminal nodes: 4
```

And then a selection of predicted paths as in the other discussion you linked:

```
pathpred(modParty)[c(1, 51, 101), ]
##       response prob.setosa prob.versicolor prob.virginica
## 1       setosa  1.00000000      0.00000000     0.00000000
## 51  versicolor  0.00000000      0.97916667     0.02083333
## 101  virginica  0.00000000      0.02173913     0.97826087
##                                                              rule
## 1                                             Petal.Length <= 1.9
## 51  Petal.Length > 1.9 & Petal.Width <= 1.7 & Petal.Length <= 4.9
## 101                        Petal.Length > 1.9 & Petal.Width > 1.7
```

I'm not sure why the method does not work for the default interface. But probably it's more difficult to set up the required model frame. You might consider asking the `C50` maintainer about this, though.

Comment: If this solved your question, please consider accepting the answer so that it is correctly flagged here on SO, thanks.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit slow. This is a great and very convenient answer to the original question. That's why I decided to mark it as accepted. However why I did not mark it as accepted until now was due to the fact that I have still some trouble with the unexported function. But as this is a different topic, I opened another question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37515454/3695715. But maybe you can help me there as well? I already tried everything I could think of...
Thank you again for your answer on this one!