# Can I store ctree splitting rules and terminal nodes plots in a table?

Tags: r, party, ctree

I would like to create a table to summarise the splitting rules of a conditional inference tree (ctree) so that each predictor is in a separate column and each row is a terminal node with corresponding values from each of the predictors. For example:

```
IrisTree <- ctree(Species ~ ., data = iris)
```

which results in this tree:

[image: ctree on iris data]

and store the results in a way such as  below:

[image: summary table]

Also, I would like to embed in a last column each of the plots resulting at terminal nodes, but I am struggling to find a way to store plots separately. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

#### Split rules

The split summary can be built on the (still unexported) function `.list.rules.party()`:

```
partykit:::.list.rules.party(IrisTree)
##                                                               2 
##                                           "Petal.Length <= 1.9" 
##                                                               5 
## "Petal.Length > 1.9 & Petal.Width <= 1.7 & Petal.Length <= 4.8" 
##                                                               6 
##  "Petal.Length > 1.9 & Petal.Width <= 1.7 & Petal.Length > 4.8" 
##                                                               7 
##                        "Petal.Length > 1.9 & Petal.Width > 1.7"
```

For further processing of split summaries, see also the following answers:

- [Get decision tree rule/path pattern for every row of predicted dataset for rpart/ctree package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618490/get-decision-tree-rule-path-pattern-for-every-row-of-predicted-dataset-for-rpart/29638602#29638602)
- [How to extract the split points of mob()](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/354066/how-to-extract-the-split-points-of-mob/354068#354068)

#### Plotting subtrees

The individual plots can be easily obtained by subsetting the tree suitably. In general if `tree` is a `party` object, then `tree[i]` is the `party` object rooted in Node `i`. These can still be plotted as before.

Thus, when selecting and plotting only a terminal node, this gives you the panel from that terminal node:

```
plot(IrisTree[5])
```

[image: terminal node 5 from iris tree]